# Store regex pattern in a variable in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line-interface

I have the following bash script code:

```
GOAL="${1:-help}"
TARGET="${2}"
MODULES_LIST="app|tester"

echo "-> Running $TARGET..."
MODULES_LIST_PATTERN = "^($MODULES_LIST)$"
if [[ "$TARGET" =~ $MODULES_LIST_PATTERN ]]; then
    run_${TARGET}
else
    print_error "You must include an existing module: {$MODULES_LIST}"
    exit 1
fi
```

As you can see, I have a `MODULES_LIST` variable where I store the modules supported by the application, then I create a regex pattern `MODULES_LIST_PATTERN` containing the value of the previous var, and use it to check if the provided parameter matches any of the modules. However, it is not working as expected, since when I run `./myscript.sh run app` it prints `ERROR] You must include an existing module: {app|tester}`.

Could someone tell me the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault... the problem is `MODULES_LIST_PATTERN = "^($MODULES_LIST)$"`, you can't have whitespaces surrounding the equals sign. After fixing that, it works as expected.

Comment: Appreciate you coming back to this and answering it immensely!